# In Blackjack, does the dealer reveal his hole card if you bust?

Tags: blackjack

I specifically like to know whether the dealer reveals his hole card when you bust in Atlantic City casinos (if the dealer doesn't have Blackjack).

Or does the dealer just pull the card away without turning it over?

Answer (score 4):

I've never played in Atlantic City, but I have played in casinos in several other places, and I have never encountered a game where the dealer doesn't show the hole card every time, even if there are no player hands in play due to busts or blackjacks. I'm pretty sure gaming laws or regulations require this in most places.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you are not the only player at the table. So if ANYone stays, the blackjack dealer must reveal his hole card to that person/people.

But if everyone busts, that's a different story.

Comment: If everyone busts the dealer does NOT reveal the hole card?

Comment: @Jackmc1047 - depending on the casino (or other setting), will determine whether or not it must be shown. If all players bust, though, why would they *have* to?

Comment: @warren Obviously, it's to their advantage not to. I'm trying to build a Blackjack simulator that can also teach card counting so I'm trying to use the same rules and practices that Atlantic City casinos use.

Answer (score 2):

The dealer is required to show the hole card even if all players bust. There isn't a casino anywhere that I've played where that isn't the rule of the house. Not showing the hole card would open the pandora's box of the casino dealing a fair game- regardless of whether or not that would even be a realistic probability.

Comment: There is an existing answer that covers the basics of this, do you have any other evidence to back up this claim?

Comment: Other than I play about 20 hours of BJ a week at a number of locations and have played all over the country and internationally, and I have never seen a game where when playing one on with the dealer the dealer does not reveal the hole card after player breaks. THIS IS NOT TO SAY IT DOES NOT EXIST. It might. In the USA, all games - every single game and all it's variants must be approved by the states gaming commission. There are face down black jack variants, but cards are eventually shown. Here's NV. https://gaming.nv.gov/index.aspx?page=51

Comment: I'd also add that not revealing the dealers hole card creates a break of the game's integrity- even though the player has busted, the dealer should in theory show a non-busting hand. What if the dealer accidentally pulled two cards which were stuck together from the shoe for the hole card? That would be deferred to the Pit Boss who would yield that round to all players at the table for straight money back. Misdeals happen all the time, dealers skip a bet, miss a players hit or hit when they want to stand, and every time the player is given the choice to keep it, or take the bet off.

Comment: Most casinos I play at they will also show the discards when a new deck is shuffled into play, or there is a dealer change. Some dealers simply discard, and if you ask to see, they will show you. I've never been told no although I don't typically ask- because a single card on a six deck shoe at the start of the deck has practically zero impact on the true count of the action. The only time when the discard would have an impact would be when you are down to the last 1/2 or 1/4 deck of the playable penetration- and the TC is very positive or very negative, where a single card would change the TC

Comment: Your comments would be much better edited into your answer